# What order should experiences be listed in?

Tags: feature-request, jobs, experience

In my own CV and most CVs that I read, the work experience section is presented in reverse chronological order, i.e. with the most recent (and therefore presumably relevant) experience appearing first on the page.  Given the limited mechanism in "careers" to easily move the experiences around and that new experiences are always added at the bottom, the site seemingly encourages chronological order instead.  Even the section names "Experience 3" seem to encourage this.  Is this intentional?

Assuming it isn't then can we have a facility to add entries to the top? or move entries to the top? Or maybe just a checkbox to present the experiences in reverse order would be best? What UI would work best?

Answer (score 4):

That's correct:  Reverse chronological order [is the 'preferred' set-up for experience](http://www.quintcareers.com/best_resume_format.html). I believe it's planned to allow you to switch the order of experience.

If it's JQuery; (bahahahahahahaha), then I'm sure they could just add a [drag and drop](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/bmains/archive/2009/02/20/jquery-dragging-and-dropping.aspx) move feature and send back its order to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine the way it is, and it doesn't matter the order - I prefer the order to be most recent at the top, but I haven't reordered them yet (I added them before the feature to reorder them was added). But you might want them in chronological order from oldest to most recent.

Comment: I disagree; the order *does* matter.  Any company or recruiter I've talked to (or even any myriad of best practices for Resumes on the internet) all say that if you're in a IT type field, it should be reverse chronological order.

Comment: George, I've seen resume formats that say just the opposite - most recent at the bottom. I'm not a fan of that, but it's personal preference. If you are qualified, I don't think you'll not get a job just because your most recent job was at the bottom of a list...

Comment: Recruiters and Companies generally get lots of resumes; anything that makes your resume harder to read (or out of the norm) is another reason to throw it away. Don't give them that reason.

Comment: But are those types of recruiters and companies really the target audience for careers.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @matt b: Hard to say. If Corporate HR is doing the looking, then yes. If it's a small ISV, then no. But do you want to take the chance?